# Merge statement join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

`MERGE` statement uses which join? How can I optimize my merge statement for a large table, so that it will not take more time to execute.

Please help.

Comment: It will use whatever JOIN you define - preferably an INNER JOIN on a common column for both the source and the target table you define

Comment: suppose i am using the join(existing.column1=new.column1) in the query. how i will mention the join?

Comment: I want to optimise the insert and update statement in a merge statement.

Comment: Your MERGE statement should be something like `MERGE (target) USING (source) ON --here comes **your** JOIN condition-- ...` - so what exactly is your question?? Do you already have a MERGE statement ?? If so: please can you post that??

Comment: What statement do you want to optimize?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260305/t-sql-is-it-possible-to-do-an-update-insert-with-a-single-fast-operation/8260396#8260396 - show how to fundamentally structure your MERGE statement.

Comment: @marc_s - Even if the merge statement has an `inner join` the actual logical join type you get depends on what `WHEN MATCHED` clauses you include. `@akd das`. You could get any logical join type or any physical join type depending on what clauses you have and what your join condition and indexes are. This question is not answerable as stated. It is far too general. You may as well ask how to optimise a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score -4):

try 'UNION' keyword ex.

```
 Select * from table1
 UNION
 Select * from table2
```